# Umbraco 7: How to get child nodes in a Layout (.cshtml)

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

This is what I am doing

[image]

This is the code circled red (where it throws an error):

```
@foreach (var slide in Model.Children)
```

I thought you used to be able to do something like that in Umbraco 4.7.

How do you loop through the child nodes correctly in Umbraco 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have access to **CurrentPage** which is a dynamic Umbraco model.

So like

```
@foreach (var slide in CurrentPage.Children)
{
    <p>@slide.Name</p>
}
```

On side node: Instead of using *Umbraco.Field("pageName")*, Use **CurrentPage.PageName**.

Comment: You can also use `Model.Content.Children` if you'd like a slightly more strongly typed version of the current page.